# How to configure http.conf without a ServerName?

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I've the following example given to me to set up rails on CentOS with apache / passenger:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
RailsEnv development
ServerName app.com
ServerAlias www.app.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/final_app/public
<directory /var/www/html/final_app/public>
AllowOverride all
Options -MultiViews
</directory>
</virtualhost>
```

Are ServerName / ServerAlias *required*? I want the site to be accesssed by IP and port, like 123.123.321:1337.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved itself. Apache will set 127.0.0.1 as ServerName if it isn't resolved.

Comment: That's actually not what apache does. What happens is that requests that don't match a servername are always handled by the first virtual host. So typing localhost or 127.0.0.1 in your browser will in this case lead to the default virtual host being served.